# "Show More" Link for buttons inside div (multiple show more buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcvsbsdy/) And this is my code here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "button.playtrailer" ).eq(2).after('<a href="" id="particular">....Show More</a>');//add a unique id to link
  $( "button.playtrailer:gt(2)" ).addClass('hide');
});

$(document).on('click','a#particular',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $('button.playtrailer').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide 
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>div1</p>
<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div2</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div3</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>
```

**What I want?**

In this code, There is only 1 `Show More Link` for all buttons inside a div.

I want different show more buttons for each div, something like this:

> div1
>
> Trailer 1   Trailer 2   Trailer HD...Show more
>
> div2
>
> Trailer 1   Trailer 2   Trailer HD...Show more
>
> div3
>
> Trailer 1   Trailer 2   Trailer HD...Show more

I want to do this without changing the class (both in div and button). What changes should, I make in my Jquery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add show more after 3 links inside every `.trailerdiv`. Also when a show more link is clicked look for hidden buttons inside its parent and show them, instead of showing all hidden buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".trailerdiv" ).each(function(){
      $(this).children(".playtrailer").eq(2).after('<a href="" id="particular">....Show More</a>');//add a unique id to link
      $(this).children(".playtrailer:gt(2)" ).addClass('hide');
  });
});

$(document).on('click','a#particular',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $(this).parent().children('button.playtrailer').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide 
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>div1</p>
<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div2</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div3</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would be acceptable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){     
  $('div').each(function(){
    $(this).children().slice(2).addClass('hide');
  });
  $('div').append('<a href="">....Show More</a>');
});

$(document).on('click','a',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().children().removeClass('hide');
  $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide 
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>div1</p>
<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div2</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div3</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>
```

What i changed : 
I add `hide` class to all buttons in each div exept first 2,
and each `a` tag opens only his div's buttons

Also you wrote `//add a unique id to link` but each link is same as previous, so they are not unique

Comment: Don't repeat ID in page...they are unique by definition

Comment: @charlietfl you'r absolutly right, I forgot to delete it :)

Comment: This code will do this to all buttons instead of buttons with `playtrailer` class

Comment: @Toby I see no problem to replase `.children()` with `.find('.playtrailer')`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/mcvsbsdy/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.trailerdiv').each(function() {
   $($(this).children()[2]).nextAll().addClass('hide');
   $($(this).children()[2]).after('<a href="" id="particular">....Show More</a>');
  })
});

$(document).on('click','a#particular',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('hide');
  $(this).nextAll().removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide 
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>div1</p>
<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div2</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>

<p>div3</p>

<div class="trailerdiv">
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 1 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 2 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer HD </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 5 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Trailer 8 </button>
<button class="playtrailer">Video 3 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isolate instances inside the parent `trailerdiv`. Use the parent as the start point and use `find()` or `children()` to look only inside that parent instance.

Also need to change the `#particular` to a class since ID's must be unique

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trailerdiv').each(function() {
    // "this" is the instance of "trailerdiv"        
    var $btns = $(this).find("button.playtrailer");
    $btns.eq(2).after('<a href="" class="show-more">....Show More</a>'); //add a unique id to link
    $btns.filter(':gt(2)').addClass('hide');
  });
});

$(document).on('click', 'a.show-more', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // only remove hide class from this button instance's siblings
  $(this).addClass('hide').siblings().removeClass('hide');

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mcvsbsdy/1/)**</kbd>